# Create a web page to control a C# windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, html

I have developed a C# windows application with Visual Studio 2013. It runs on a server and communicates with some devices around the world through a Apache server(txt files which contains commands). Now I would need to create a web page(accessible via the internet) which allows my customers to log in and change some parameters which are in my windows application.What would be the best way to do it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Web applications can't affect applications on your computer. Think about the security implications if they could. You're going to have to store the parameters somewhere that the web application can control and have the windows application retrieve them from there.

Comment: I'd use socket programming. And Identity or some other custom authentication layer

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a web page to save customer settings in database
2. Expose a webservice or Web API that can be called from the desktop application in a different thread to access the customer data from the web